# How to fix vagrant up error related to NFS issue?

Tags: nfs, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I ran into a very strange issue this morning. When I rebooted my machine, and tried to run `vagrant up`, I get this error;

```
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
mount -o vers=3,rw,tcp,nolock,noacl,async 10.0.1.1:/Users/me/code /vagrant
Stdout from the command:
Stderr from the command:
mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported
```

I didn't change any configuration settings, or update my machine or anything. Of things I know, nothing has changed. What gives? Anyone have any ideas as to what the issue is and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that runs into this same issue and none of the other solutions you find seem to work, my issue was `127.0.0.1 localhost` missing from my `/etc/hosts` file. Not sure how or why it went missing, but when adding this back, it fixed the issue.